# Name for a property that is like distributivity, but for power over sum or derivative over multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra

When $(a + b)σ$ = $aσ + bσ$, we say $σ$ distributes over $+$.

- Ordinary multiplication distributes over ordinary summation.
- In a vector field, application of a linear function distributes over vector summation.

It is very nice to have a word for this property.

Another time we may see a rule such that: $$(a \times b)τ = aτ \times b + a \times bτ + aτ \times bτ$$ − Or that: $$(a + b)τ = aτ \times bτ^- + aτ^- \times bτ + 2 \times a \times b$$

- A derivative of a product of functions (before we apply the [Transcendental law of homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_law_of_homogeneity)) obeys the first variant: $(a b)' = a' b + a b' + a' b'$.
- Ordinary square of ordinary sum obeys the second variant: $(a^1 + b^1)^2 = a^2b^0 + a^0b^2 + 2a^1b^1$.

These two examples keep following a similar pattern if we apply $τ$ further, iteratively. Visually, they both have something to do with a slicing of a hyper-interval.

Is there a name for rules like these?

Comment: In a word, No..

Comment: @Lubin "Unfortunately no", or "no for a good reason", or some other kind of "no"?

Comment: Technically, it is not true that $(ab)'=a'b+ab'+a'b'.$ It is true that $d(ab)=(da)b+a(db)+(da)(db).$ $d$ is not a map from functions to functions, but something more abstract. But if we divide by $dx$ on both sides, you get $(ab)'=a'b+ab'+a'b'dx.$

Comment: And even $a'b'\,dx$ is not a real function, so you are going to have to go to some slightly more complicated space.

Comment: A better example is the discrete difference, $\Delta=\Delta_{\epsilon}$, where $\Delta_{\epsilon}(f)(x)=f(x+\epsilon)-f(x).$ Then $$\Delta(fg)=(f+\Delta(f))(g+\Delta(g))-fg=\Delta(f)\cdot g+f\cdot (\Delta g)+\Delta(f)\cdot \Delta(g)$$

Comment: However, if you used $D=D_{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Delta_{\epsilon},$ the discrete derivative, then you'd get $$D(fg)=(Df)g+f(Dg)+\epsilon (Df)(Dg)$$ So you obviously have a general rule: $(ab)\sigma = (a\sigma)b+a(b\sigma)+C(a\sigma)(b\sigma)$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: (BTW, the big difference in your two examples is that the squaring operator is not linear. )

Comment: What is $\tau^{-}$ in the case of the squaring operator? Or maybe I'm confused about what $\tau$ is supposed to be in the squaring operator. We have $(a+b)^2=a\tau +b\tau +2ab$, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My idea is that $τ$ is raising the power, while $τ^-$ is lowering it.

Comment: But that's really strange, and doesn't work in general, only in the case of $2$, when $\tau^{-}b=1.$ Can you think of a case where there is a non-trivial $\tau^{-}?$? This would then be a condition on two transformations, $\tau$ and $\tau^{-},$ unless you could explain how $\tau^{-}$ is defined in terms of the operator $\tau.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought we may say $xτ^n = x^{(n+1)}$ and $τ^- = τ^{-1}$.